# Trigger DAG Run on environment startup/restart

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way to trigger a DAG every time the airflow environment is brought up? This would be helpful to run some tests on the environment

Answer (score 0):

You can moniter the boot time of system or process and check the last_execution datetime of Dag and accordingly trigger the dag.

You can refer to following code

```
import psutil
from datetime import datetime
last_reboot = psutil.boot_time()
boot_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(last_reboot)

Variable.set('boot_time',boot_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
last_run_dt = Variable.get('last_run_end_date',"")
try:
    from dateutil import parser

    if last_run_dt == "":
        last_run_at = parser.parse('1970-01-01 00:00:00')
    else:
        last_run_at = parser.parse(last_run_dt)

    if boot_time > last_run_at:
        # Your code to trigger the Dag
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).